# How do I solve the differential equation?.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the differential equation?.
$$
(2x+2xy^2)dx+(x^2y+2y+3y^3)dy=0
$$
I determine the integration factor
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}
$$
but I got confused with the next step, is this procedure ok?

[[**My exercise**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSvh.png)]

Comment: The procedure is incorrect. The idea of the integrating factor is only applicable to equations that are inexact or equations that are linear. This equation is neither.

Comment: @Angel I think this is an inexact differential equation; I also think that this integrating factor does indeed make the equation exact so the solution should be ok

Comment: @layabout You are correct; an integrating factor is appropriate here, and OP has found the correct one.

Comment: You are correct. It does work. It appears I made a mistake when verifying the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the procedure is correct. To verify your work, I first rewrite the equation as $2x(1+y^2)\mathrm{d}x+[yx^2+(2y+3y^3)]\mathrm{d}y=0$. Utilizing the integrating factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$, one obtains $2x\sqrt{1+y^2}\mathrm{d}x+\left[\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}x^2+\frac{2y+3y^3}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right]\mathrm{d}y=0$. It is now easy to verify that $\partial_y(2x\sqrt{1+y^2})=\partial_x\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}x^2+\frac{2y+3y^3}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)=\frac{2xy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$, since the former is simply evaluating $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\mathrm{d}y}$$ and the latter is simply evaluating $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x^2}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$